# AAPT: error: failed to deserialize resource table: configuration has invalid locale 'be-' after updating AGP

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I am getting a compilation error after updating the Gradle plugin to 7.2.1 in Android Studiio

The Error

```
AAPT: error: failed to deserialize resource table: configuration has invalid locale 'be-'.
```

Before (worked fine)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
```

Now (compilation error)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
```